# Delay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to delay my function but it's still not working.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.promos1')
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({ 'margin-top': '0px' }, 1400, 'easeOutQuint');
});
```

**Edit: working Finddle** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2p8V/)

Comment: `margin-top` should be `marginTop`

Comment: a jsfiddle for not working??

Comment: @AmitSoni: Both are valid.

Comment: @user: Works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/5VeVr/

Comment: Thanks for help! Now it's working. I forgot to include the jQuery UI library.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `easeOutQuint` option in jQuery so your code seems not working and as @cookie monster `linear` working demo.

So, This is an option of jQuery UI. You need to include the jQuery UI library.

Comment: no , there is effect called `easeOutQuint` within `jquery ui` , here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VeVr/1/)

Comment: yeah and the updated fiddle is working... and I'm saying to include jquery ui.... please read again...